# Do these hardware specs support Linux working system?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, system-installation, hardware, kubuntu

I have a PC with the following specs:

```
Processor: AMD Phenom II x6 1055T Processor, 2800 Mhz, 6 Core(s), 6 Logical Processors
RAM: 6GB
Motherboard: Gigabyte Technology GA-890-FXA-UD5
Adapter: ATI Radeon HD 5700
Hard Disk: 500GB
```

This PC has Windows 7 installed. As I can't upgrade Windows, I want to ask if with this specs I can install a (recent) Linux version e.g. Ubuntu/Kubuntu? Or which would work for a desktop with these hardware specs?

In case it helps, I would not be using it for heavy tasks such as gaming, video or image processing, streaming etc

Comment: You can install anything that you want provided that there aren't hardware checks in place such as with Windows 10 and 11 (as I'm sure you already found found) but what you most likely want to know is whether or not it will run. That depends on what you are using it for and any answers are going to be based on opinion and personal judgement.

Comment: @NasirRiley: I will **not** be using it for gaming, photo processing, streaming or similar tasks if that helps.

Comment: @Jim we can't tell you what you think is acceptable performance. This is really just asking for opinions. Performance will be comparable to what you experience on windows, when you do similar things. Voting to close as really just asking for an opinion.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: I am not asking about acceptable performance. I am asking how can I best utilize this hardware

Comment: @Jim your title definitely doesn't ask that. And the problem with "best" is that it's a subjective thing. For person A, that would be a text terminal, Person B else would want a hardware-accelerated desktop for his text processing. Can't tell you that! Also, honestly, you're *by absolutely no means* someone who's never used Linux. Installing Ubuntu takes about 15 minutes, and from that point on you can just experiment with different desktops; what could an answer here tell you that you would *not* be **better off** trying yourself?

Comment: @MarcusMüller: Fair point. I am trying to see as much info before having to wipe everything and do a fresh install for a test.

Comment: @Jim you don't have to wipe anything…

Comment: @MarcusMüller: Are you talking about dual boot keeping the Windows 7?

Comment: @Jim you could do that, but I was referring to not having to wipe anything after a Linux installation just to check a different desktop environment.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: But the PC already is setup with Windows. If not dual boot, I would have to wipe everything to test Linux right?

Comment: @Jim … as I have noted below. You can download a Ubuntu bootable stick and just try without wiping anything.

Answer (score 1):

Are those specs compatible with an Ubuntu installation?

Yes.

(And also with many other distros, based on Debian and other upstreams.)

Comment: As @NasirRiley pointed out in the comment, it is about having a workable system, not just installing. So would Ubuntu work properly?

Comment: Yes, of course it would. Ssh into it, emacs source files, run C++ compiler, do whatever. I have used debian cloud servers with less RAM than 6 GiB quite successfully. Even less than a gig. Just be sure to configure a swapfile, so that infrequently used code will get paged out to disk. // If your definition of "properly" is "workload X shall experience 95th percentile latencies less than Y", then specify what {X, Y} mean for this question.

Comment: What about the CPU. Due to CPU updating to Windows 11 is impossible. Would the specific CPU generation be fine with Ubuntu?

Comment: @Jim honestly, that is written on the Ubuntu download page, and inserting the bootable USB stick, which takes 2 minutes to make will tell you that, will give you certainty. For less effort than asking us here, or us answering here!

Comment: You’ve got half a dozen cores running at nearly three gigahertz. Reduce the clock to 2 GHz and it will still work just fine, with very snappy performance on your interactive ssh session, no hiccups. Save on heat dissipation by reducing to 1 GHz, and it will STILL work just fine. // Maybe you have a real question to ask? One that involves numeric performance measurements?

Comment: I am asking because the CPU is not compatible with running recent versions of Windows anymore. I wasn't sure if there would be an issue with Linux as well.

Comment: Is the CPU an Intel 286 that doesn’t offer a proper MMU for addressing virtual memory? No. Is it a 386 or 486 that some kernels choose not to support due to usermode security risks? No. Is it even a Pentium? No. Just look at the clock speed. This is clearly a modern CPU. I wouldn’t use it as hypervisor for a commercial multi-tenant offering, due to cache timing issues. But that’s not your proposed use case. INSTALL UBUNTU already, and report back on ACTUAL observations of how the target system behaved under described workloads of interest. “Hypotheticals R us?” No!